# Fast way to select random rows from table based on sum of a field

Tags: mysql, algorithm, relational-database

I have a table consisting of information regarding hundreds of meals.

I want to quickly select a specific number of random rows such that the sum of their calorie fields is equal to some number.

Consider the following use case:

If a user wants 1000 calories spread over 3 meals per day, the system should return 3 different meals randomly, which sum to 1000 calories.

I can think of naive ways of doing this, like the following one, but I want a more scalable approach.

Naive approach:
From my Python script, I run the following query in a while loop:

```
SELECT * FROM meal WHERE RAND()<=0.0005;
```

I calculate the number `0.005` by taking the number of meals given by the user, say `3` and then dividing it by the total number of rows in the table, say `600`. This ensures we'd get around 3 rows from the table as the result. I then sum over the `calorie` column from these rows and check whether it is equal to the amount specified by the user, say `1000 calories`. If it isn't, I continue searching for other rows - I keep the loop iterating, otherwise I quit.

Comment: Post you your `naive` attempt and explain why you are not satisfied with it.

Comment: And if this has got anything to do with relational databases, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @PM77-1 See my edit.

Comment: Your edit includes no code and code is what makes Stack Overflow work. Please, **include the code you've written so we can help you fix it.**

Comment: @tadman See my newer edit.

Comment: You've accidentally stumbled on [the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and there's many ways to solve it. If you're using the random approach then you need to pick N random combinations, sort them by the best fit, and take the winner.

Comment: @tadman That means N calls to the database?

Comment: If you use that approach, then yes, but these should take only a fraction of a millisecond on modern hardware. You could also load data representing the options into Python, shuffle them up there, and find the best fit. It's worth reading that Wikipedia page for better ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following simplified example, which demonstrates, to varying degree, both how to ask a question and how to answer one:

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT i1.i meal1
     , i2.i meal2
     , i3.i meal3
     , i1.i+i2.i+i3.i 
  FROM ints i1 
  JOIN ints i2 
    ON i2.i > i1.i 
  JOIN ints i3 
    ON i3.i > i2.i 
 WHERE i1.i+i2.i+i3.i BETWEEN 18 AND 20;

+-------+-------+-------+----------------+
| meal1 | meal2 | meal3 | i1.i+i2.i+i3.i |
+-------+-------+-------+----------------+
|     1 |     8 |     9 |             18 |
|     2 |     7 |     9 |             18 |
|     2 |     8 |     9 |             19 |
|     3 |     6 |     9 |             18 |
|     3 |     7 |     8 |             18 |
|     3 |     7 |     9 |             19 |
|     3 |     8 |     9 |             20 |
|     4 |     5 |     9 |             18 |
|     4 |     6 |     8 |             18 |
|     4 |     6 |     9 |             19 |
|     4 |     7 |     8 |             19 |
|     4 |     7 |     9 |             20 |
|     5 |     6 |     7 |             18 |
|     5 |     6 |     8 |             19 |
|     5 |     6 |     9 |             20 |
|     5 |     7 |     8 |             20 |
+-------+-------+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: An `ORDER BY` on the last column would promote the best fit, too.

Comment: Where's the random factor here?

Comment: I've deliberately left that as an exercise for the reader (albeit, a very easy exercise)

Comment: And what if I've got 5 meals to show? How would I join a variable number of tables?

Comment: @SamChats You've uncovered the fundamental limitation with this solution. Luckily, most people consume a finite (and small) number of meals per day - especially when they're counting calories.

Comment: But they can still choose a variable number of meals, however small that may be, and won't joins be slower than my naive approach?

Comment: Relational databases love joins. I don't really understand your naive approach.

Comment: So joins will be faster than simple selects?

Comment: I imagine that some implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm would be more efficient, but that's not what sql's good at.